# How can I add a cdata block using GDataXMLNode?

Tags: iphone, xml

I've tried this:

```
GDataXMLElement * body = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"body"];
[body addChild:[GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"request" stringValue:@"<![CDATA[ <hello> ]]>"]];
NSLog(@"%@",[body XMLString]);
```

And it outputs:

`<body`>`<request`>`&`lt`;![CDATA[`&lt`;hello`&gt`; ]]`&gt`;`<`/request`>`<`/body`>

But want it to be like this:

`<body`>`<request`><![CDATA[ <hello> ]]>`<`/request`>`<`/body`>

any idea how can I tell the parser that the GDataXMLNode should be a CDATA kind?

Comment: Ever find out? I'd like to know too.

Comment: Also, this results in the CDATA stripped out altogether: GDataXMLElement * n = [[GDataXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<mytag><![CDATA[mystring]]></mytag>" error:nil];

Comment: so you get <mytag>mystring</mytag>

Answer (score 2):

Did you trying using:

```
[[GDataXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:"<![CDATA[ .... ]]>"]
```

Baseed on the source this parses it directly as XML:

```
const char *utf8Str = [str UTF8String];
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory(utf8Str, (int)strlen(utf8Str), NULL, // URL
                              NULL, // encoding
                              kGDataXMLParseOptions);
```

Whereas `elementWithName` just grabs the string verbatim:

```
+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementWithName:(NSString *)name {
    xmlNodePtr theNewNode = xmlNewNode(NULL, // namespace
                                       GDataGetXMLString(name));
    if (theNewNode) {
    // succeeded
    return [self nodeConsumingXMLNode:theNewNode];
}
return nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this thread is old, I thought it might be helpful for someone stumbling into this.

GDataXML does not have support for CData implemented. But, it looks easy to add this functionality.  GDataXML uses libxml2 to create XML document. In libxml2 CData section could be created as suggested in [how to write a CDATA node using libxml2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632844/how-to-write-a-cdata-node-using-libxml2) .

So, we could enhance

`+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementWithName:(NSString *)name stringValue:(NSString *)value`

method of GDataXMLNode to have a boolean parameter indicating whether we need CData node and modify the line

```
 xmlNodePtr textNode = xmlNewText(GDataGetXMLString(value));
```

to create CData Block instead of a text block

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to GDataXMLNode.h

```
+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementWithName:(NSString *)name cDataStringValue:(NSString *)value;
- (void)setCDataStringValue:(NSString *)value;
```

Add the following to GDataXMLNode.m

```
+ (GDataXMLElement *)elementWithName:(NSString *)name cDataStringValue:(NSString *)value {

    xmlNodePtr theNewNode = xmlNewNode(NULL, // namespace
                                       GDataGetXMLString(name));
    if (theNewNode) {

        NSUInteger length = [value lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        xmlNodePtr textNode = xmlNewCDataBlock(theNewNode->doc, GDataGetXMLString(value), length);

        if (textNode) {

            xmlNodePtr temp = xmlAddChild(theNewNode, textNode);
            if (temp) {
                // succeeded
                return [self nodeConsumingXMLNode:theNewNode];
            }
        }

        // failed; free the node and any children
        xmlFreeNode(theNewNode);
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)setCDataStringValue:(NSString *)value {

    if (xmlNode_ != NULL && value != nil) {

        NSUInteger length = [value lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        xmlNodePtr textNode = xmlNewCDataBlock(xmlNode_->doc, GDataGetXMLString(value), length);

        if (textNode) {

            xmlAddChild(xmlNode_, textNode);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need the setCDataStringValue method for this example but I included it anyway, so you can optionally create the GDataXMLNode and add the CData later.

Your example would then become:

```
GDataXMLElement * body = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"body"];
GDataXMLElement * response = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"response" cDataStringValue:@"<hello>"];
[body addChild:response];
NSLog(@"%@",[body XMLString]);
```

Which outputs:

```
<body><response><![CDATA[<hello>]]></response></body>
```