# how to write a CDATA node using libxml2?

Tags: libxml2, cdata

I'm using libxml2 to read/write xml files.  Now I'm trying to write a CDATA node.

Here is what I tried:

```
nodePtr = xmlNewChild( parentPtr, NULL, "foo", NULL );
xmlNodeSetContentLen( nodePtr, "<![CDATA[\nTesting 1 < 2\n]]>", len );
```

However, this results in the following encoded text:

```
<foo>&lt;![CDATA[
Testing 1 &lt; 2
]]&gt;</foo>
```

I'm thinking that perhaps there might be a CDATA-specific libxml2 API.  Or maybe I have to call something else to tell libxml2 not to automatically encode the node content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  The trick is in knowing that CDATA text content is actually a child and not a part of the current node, and the critical API to call is xmlNewCDataBlock().  Using the same example as above:

```
nodePtr = xmlNewChild( parentPtr, NULL, "foo", NULL );
cdataPtr = xmlNewCDataBlock( doc, "Testing 1 < 2", 13 );
xmlAddChild( nodePtr, cdataPtr );
```

This will produce the following xml:

```
<foo><![CDATA[Testing 1 < 2]]></foo>
```

Comment: Stéphane What is the doc in the second line of the code. Is it a docptr. Is there  a way to do without using docptr.

Comment: @Stephane xmlNewChild takes 3 parameters. not 4.

Comment: @milaniez Note that I wrote this in 2011.  Lots of things have changed between 2011 and 2017!

Comment: @Stéphane My bad! It does take 4 arguments.

Comment: @KranthiKumar How about `cdataPtr = xmlNewCDataBlock( parentPtr->doc, "Testing 1 < 2", 13 );` ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for all versions of libxml2, but according to libxml2-2.9.4 the `doc` part of returning node of `xmlNewChild` comes from its parent. Also the parent of child node returned from `xmlNewCDataBlock` is set by doc parameter. So the following would be a good practice:

```
const char str[] = "said the kitty";
xmlNodePtr node = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "meow");
xmlNodePtr cdata_node = xmlNewCDataBlock(node->doc, BAD_CAST str, strlen(str));
xmlAddChild(node, cdata_node);
```

The resulting xml is

```
<meow><![CDATA[said the kitty]]></meow>
```

And it would not matter if `node` is part of an `xmlDoc` or not